# How to run two nodes on the same device?

Tags: go-ethereum

I want to run two separate nodes on my computer but it seems that the two nodes will collide with other. I know some considerations should be taken such as the ports, but anything else should I take care of?

Answer (score 6):

#### Different clients

For different clients all you need to do is changing the listening port, like that:

```
pyethapp # defaults to 30303
eth --listen 30304 --no-ipc
geth --port 30305 # default ipc
parity --port 30306
```

In `ethereumj` you can configure the port in the config file, e.g., `30307`. Never was able to change the port in pyethapp though. Running parity in `--geth` mode here would conflict with geth, depending on your needs you should disable ipc on all clients except one, the example above defaults to geth ipc.

#### Same client

For multiple instances of the same client, you would also have to adjust the data directory.

```
geth # defaults to port 30303 and ~/.ethereum
geth --port 30304 --datadir ~/.ethereum-04
geth --port 30305 --datadir ~/.ethereum-05
geth --port 30306 --datadir ~/.ethereum-06
```

Or for parity:

```
parity # defaults to port 30303 and ~/.parity
parity --port 30304 --db-path ~/.parity-04
parity --port 30305 --db-path ~/.parity-05
parity --port 30306 --db-path ~/.parity-06
```

On top you can add fine tuning such as rpc ports or pruning methods, but that's up to you.

Comment: So if I started $geth and it's syncing i.e. `"Imported new chain segment"` etc that is already 1 instance being used for syncing on port `30303`. So if I want to start another instance of geth in bash so I can run other bash commands like `geth --dev`, `geth console`, `geth --exec`, I have to open a 2nd instance by using `geth --port 30304 --datadir ~/.ethereum-04`? Can I just use `geth --port 30304` and geth will auto increment the directory? Also I don't have a `~/.ethereum` directory. Only a `$HOME/Library/Ethereum` directory.

Answer (score 3):

I have successfully used this docker-compose system, where you can even define the number of nodes as a parameter:

https://github.com/stevebakh/docker-ethereum

Comment: It enables the user develop a private network on one device?

Comment: you know docker... creates many virtual devices on one computer

Answer (score 3):

If you're running 2 nodes on the same user profile, you need to use different `datadirs` for each node. Although not efficient, you can also run a node on a virtual Guest OS through hypervisors like VirtualBox.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you will have to use different ports and directories for the data of each node.
I shared a docker-compose (Geth+Parity) setup, on the same host. You can use that example to start. Cheers!
https://github.com/gregbkr/ethereum-nodes-docker

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.