# Can we run GETH light client and full client at same server at the same time?

Tags: go-ethereum

I have a dumb question. Can we run light client and full client at the same time in the same server? I want this because the server where I was running full node crashed. After recovery, GETH node is not working at all. So, just to be on safe side I also want to run a light client where if need be, I will point my web3 provider IPC to the light client.
Thanks

Comment: If you do this at enterprise level, why do you have a full node if a light one is enough ?

Comment: Hey @FlorianCastelain Thanks for the question. I wanted to experiment with light nodes which is downloading right now just to see if it can do the required tasks. The full node crashed and is still not running so wanted to use light client. Do you know if a light client can invoke a function of a smart contract?

Comment: You can find a lot on Internet about the difference of light and full node. Basically, light node cannot validate transactions and requires a contact to a full node to validate something as the light node mostly only have block headers. But I'm not sure about that last part.

Answer (score 1):

Just need to change the port for light client and default datadirectory:

```
geth # defaults to port 30303 and ~/.ethereum
geth --syncmode light --port 30304 --datadir ~/.ethereum-02
```

Reference:
[How to run two nodes on the same device?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7006/how-to-run-two-nodes-on-the-same-device)