# Testing smart contract on network with multiple nodes

Tags: contract-design, contract-deployment, network

Newbie here, wondering if this is possible:

I’m doing research on implementing a smart contract on a network with multiple nodes. I need to be able to deploy the contract (on a test network) and observe that multiple nodes interacted with it under my control. Here’s a simple example using the highest bidder scenario.

-3 nodes, say that the network is holding an auction to win something.

-nodes 2 and 3 interact with the contract by submitting bids, the contract does the checks and dispenses the reward to the highest bidder (in this case, node 1 is not interacting).

I need to be able to submit bids for both nodes 2 and 3 in order to support my research (equivalently, showing that multiple nodes interacted with the contract). Is this possible with a test environment? Or am I limited to interaction from only one node?

Comment: You can run multiple geth instances on the same machine. Read here for more details https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7006/how-to-run-two-nodes-on-the-same-device.

Comment: @Ismael, thanks for the link. I've been reading a little on Ganache (IDE preferred since this is very new to me), and it looks like you can create multiple clients in their private network...is this the same technique?

Comment: I won't work, ganache is just a single process test client. It cannot be connected to multiple instances sharing state. You can run multiple ganache instances independently, but they won't share the same blockchain data, contracts, transactions, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea, I don’t know if this is the most efficient one.

Deploy the contract to Goerli test network.

Than you can access Infura nodes, try registering 3 times to get 3 different nodes.

And with a simple Python script (web3.py) you can interact with the contract using every time a different node.